# Issue with linking torch and hdf5 lib together

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, hdf5

I'm trying to set up my project in C++ with HDF5 file usages and pyTorch (C++ API), and there are some linking problem.

So... I run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I had installed HDF5 with APT, then I download zip from pyTorch and put it into third_party dir in my project structure.

```
project/   
--data/  
----data.h5  
--third_party/  
----libtorch/  
--main.cpp  
--CMakeLists.txt  
--run.sh
```

My main.cpp looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include "H5Cpp.h"

#define PRINT(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl;

const H5std_string FILE_NAME("real/path/to/project/data/data.h5");

int main() {

    // Create a vector of inputs.
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(torch::ones({1, 3, 3, 3}));

    H5::H5File file(FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
}
```

Then CMakeLists:

```
project(cpptorch)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# pyTorch
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

# HDF5
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS C CXX HL REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${HDF5_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

add_executable(cpptorch main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(cpptorch ${HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(cpptorch ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})
```

And run.sh

```
parent_path=$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )

mkdir -p ${parent_path}/build
cd ${parent_path}/build
echo ${parent_path}
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${parent_path}/third_party/libtorch ..
make 
./cpptorch 
cd ..
```

And now I'll describe the issue. For example, when in CMake I comment out all lines connected with HDF5 then torch works fine, same when I comment out Torch's lines in CMake - HDF5 runs well. But when I try to run above code I receive errors:

```
CMakeFiles/cpptorch.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `H5::H5File::H5File(std::string const&, unsigned int, H5::FileCreatPropList const&, H5::FileAccPropList const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cpptorch.dir/build.make:92: recipe for target 'cpptorch' failed
make[2]: *** [cpptorch] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cpptorch.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpptorch.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
./run.sh: line 8: ./cpptorch: No such file or directory
```

If anybody have any idea how to solve it? I find it as linking problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hello, could solve your problem?